# Клиент-серверное приложение на Python

Tags: python, сокеты

Хотел чтобы при отправке запроса на сервер, он выполнял команду и возвращал то что он вывел.

Шаги:

1. С клиент на сервер пишу "123"
2. Сервер выполняет команду
3. Дальше сервер должен отправить то что он вывел на клиент

Извините, в питоне я новичок. Не ругайте пожалуйста

Клиент:

```
from socket import *
import sys
import PySimpleGUI as sg        


host = 'localhost'
port = 777
addr = (host,port)

tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcp_socket.connect(addr)


data = input('write to server: ')
if not data : 
    tcp_socket.close() 
    sys.exit(1)


data = str.encode(data)
tcp_socket.send(data)
data = bytes.decode(data)
data = tcp_socket.recv(1024)
print(data)
```

Сервер:

```
from socketserver import *
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os
import psutil



host = 'localhost'
port = 777
addr = (host,port)


class MyTCPHandler(StreamRequestHandler):


    def handle(self):     
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
        print ('client send: '+str(self.data))


        if self.data == b'123':
            cpu = psutil.cpu_times()
            conn.send(b'1233')





if __name__ == "__main__":


    server = TCPServer(addr, MyTCPHandler)

    print('starting server... for exit press Ctrl+C')

    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: А в чем у вас проблема? Вы хотите, чтобы сервер возвращал ответ, а он не возвращает? Или возвращает не то, что вы хотите?

Comment: Да, чтобы он выполнил if self.data == b'123':
 cpu = psutil.cpu_times() вот это и отправил то что он вывел

Comment: `conn.send(str(cpu).encode())`?